# Windows 7 Favorite folder doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, shell, favorites

So recently I did a very stupid thing and accidentally deleted my `APPDATA`, and now the favorite folder doesn't work anymore.

The favorite folder I am refering to is the one in windows explorer in windows 7, which appears on the left of windows explorer windows.

The `%USERPROFILE%/Favorite` folder still works correctly, but the favorite folder in the shell doesn't point there, instead it points to a nonexistent and broken location, how do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem is that it isn't the "favorites" folder that should be restored, it was the links folder. Favorites folder is for favorites in internet explorer, links folder is for favorites in windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in the recycle bin? if so restore it. Or,

Try a Microsoft System Restore, pick a date before you deleted that folder.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11238/using-system-restore-to-recover-your-windows-7-computer/

EDIT:

I found a way to remove Favorites from Windows Explorer, maybe you can restore it using these instructions. If the shell folder is missing you may have to create it or get a copy of it from another W7 PC.

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}\ShellFolder
>
> 1. )To get permissions, first right-click on "ShellFolder" key and select "Permissions".
>      It'll open a new window.
> 2. ) Select "Administrators" in user list and check "Allow" box given for "Full Control" permission.
> 3. ) Click on OK button to apply the changes.
> 4. Now double-click on "Attributes" DWORD value given in right-side section and change its value to a9400100
> 5. That's it. Log off or restart your system and "Favorites" will no longer present in Explorer window.
>
> NOTE: If you want to restore "Favorites" in Navigation pane, simply change value of "Attributes" DWORD to a0900100 using step 4.

.

Comment: Not worth it, the latest recovery date is right after I made a bunch of huge changes to the computer, recovering to that would do more damage than when I deleted the appdata folder.

Comment: Check my edit above.

Comment: Hmm tehse allow me to delete the favorites folder, and although it might also allow me to redirect the folder, I don't know what hex number to put in for that purpose. I also modified the HKEY_CURRENT_USER/software/microsoft/windows/explorer/shell_folders/favorites key and put in the desired path E:/Users/myUsername/favorites, but it didnt work.

Comment: Might be best to create a new user account and migrate your old profile to the new account. When you are happy with the new one, delete the old user account.

Comment: is the entirety of your user account information stored in /user/username ? Or are some settings scattered randomly across other folders?

Comment: They are in the user folder, see this page, scroll down to "Personal documents and settings for every user account"..http://www.optimizingpc.com/windows7/windows_7_multiple_useraccounts.html

Comment: Article here, scroll down to "Copying your User profile", article is for XP but is very similar prcedure for W7...http://www.lockergnome.com/it/2004/12/15/get-it-done-recover-a-damaged-windows-xp-user-profile/

Answer (score 0):

Change the location in which it points to; to the Favorites folder that you need it to be.

Comment: There's no option in the context menu